# C# HtmlAgilityPack get content from all div with given class

Tags: c#, html

I have a HTML file that looks like this:

```
<div class="user_meals">
<div class="name">Name Surname</div>
<div class="day_meals">
    <div class="meal">First Meal</div>
</div>  
<div class="day_meals">
    <div class="meal">Second Meal</div>
</div>
<div class="day_meals">

    <div class="meal">Third Meal</div>

</div>
<div class="day_meals">

    <div class="meal">Fourth Meal</div>

</div>

<div class="day_meals">

    <div class="meal">Fifth Meal</div>

</div>
```

This code repeats a few times.

I want to get **Name** and **Surname** which is between `<div>` tag with class "name".

This is my code using HtmlAgilityPack:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(@"C:\workspace\file.html");

foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='name']"))
{
    string vaule = node.InnerText;
}
```

But actually it doesn't work. Visual Studio throws me Exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong method to load HTML from a path `LoadHtml` expect HTML and not location of the file. Use `Load` instead.

The error you are getting is quite misleading as all properties are not null and standard tips from [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) don't apply.

Essentially this comes from the fact `SelectNodes` correctly returns `null` as there are not elements matching the query and `foreach` throws on it.

Fixed code:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
// either doc.Load(@"C:\workspace\file.html") or pass HTML:
doc.LoadHtml("<div class='user_meals'><div class='name'>Name Surname</div></div> ");
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='name']");
// SelectNodes returns null if nothing found - may need to check 
if (nodes == null)
{ 
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Where all my nodes???");    
}
foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    string vaule = node.InnerText;
    vaule.Dump();
}
```