# C# Get certain part of text from a webresponse

Tags: c#

So for Personal Training I am trying to create a Highscore lookup for a game.
My current code is:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/a=13/compare?user1=" + textBox1.Text);
httpWebRequest.Host = "services.runescape.com";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookie;
httpWebRequest.Referer = "Referer: http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/a=13/ranking";
httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = (long)bytes.Length;
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Origin", "services.runescape.com");
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");

Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
cookie.Add(httpWebResponse.Cookies);

StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
streamReader.Close();
httpWebResponse.Close();
```

I am trying to get the integer of the skill.
A line in the response that holds the skill level looks like the following:

```
<td class="playerWinLeft alignleft"><div class="relative">a href="services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/a=13/ranking?category_type=0&amp;table=0&amp;page=1">2,715/a></div></td>
```

The 2,715 is the part that I want to log.

Answer (score 1):

If the web page is valid XML (it isn't always) you can [load it into an XML document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azsy1tw2(v=vs.110).aspx) and find the data you need [using XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx).

If it isn't valid XML, you will need to load the HTML into an HTML parser such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Or, as a cheap solution, you could just search the string for `services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/a=13/ranking?category_type=0&amp;table=0&amp;page=1">` and take the characters immediately after, using something like [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Just use HTML Agility Pack.  Relying on a web page to conform to valid XML is a sure fire way to endless headaches.

Comment: I have never worked with this how would this work?
Is there an example?

Comment: You can probably adapt [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076207/c-sharp-htmlagilitypack-get-content-from-all-div-with-given-class) to your needs.

Comment: The thing is I am not loading it from a HTML file. I will be threading lots of usernames that will be checking the stats on.

Comment: Right.  So use `LoadHTML(string html)` instead of `Load(string file)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a packet which could help you

it's a Linq to html.
similar to Linq to Xml i think this could help you.

https://bitlush.com/linq-to-html

Answer (score -1):

You can do some Jquery Ajax and filter data if needed.

```
$(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"somePage.html",
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(data) {
                    alert(data);

                },
                error:function() {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            })
        });
```